# QWebKit linkClicked signal never fires

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwebview, qwebkit

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web_view = QWebView()
def url_changed(url):  print 'url changed: ', url
def link_clicked(url):  print 'link clicked: ', url
def load_started():  print 'load started'
def load_finished(ok):  print 'load finished, ok: ', ok
web_view.connect(web_view, SIGNAL("urlChanged(const QUrl&)"), url_changed)
web_view.connect(web_view, SIGNAL("linkClicked(const QUrl&)"), link_clicked)
web_view.connect(web_view, SIGNAL('loadStarted()'), load_started)
web_view.connect(web_view, SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'), load_finished)
web_view.load(QUrl('http://google.com'))
web_view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The linkClicked signal isn't working.  The other signals work.  Qt 4.6.2 on Win XP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [link delegation policy](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebpage.html#LinkDelegationPolicy-enum) must be set appropriately for the [linkClicked](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebview.html#linkClicked) signal to be emitted.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage, QWebView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web_view = QWebView()
web_view.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
def url_changed(url):  print 'url changed: ', url
def link_clicked(url):  print 'link clicked: ', url
def load_started():  print 'load started'
def load_finished(ok):  print 'load finished, ok: ', ok
web_view.connect(web_view, SIGNAL("urlChanged(const QUrl&)"), url_changed)
web_view.connect(web_view, SIGNAL("linkClicked(const QUrl&)"), link_clicked)
web_view.connect(web_view, SIGNAL('loadStarted()'), load_started)
web_view.connect(web_view, SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'), load_finished)
web_view.load(QUrl('http://google.com'))
web_view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```